# Selenium refresh page and resend data

Tags: api, selenium, webdriver, reload

I have this weird thing happening with my testcase, however rather than fixing it I would like to just "bypass" it for now. The following steps allow me to do that:

1) click back, to navigate browser back one page
2) refresh page
3) continue normally

however, at step two i get a confirmation modal box from firefox, asking if i want to resend the data, after clicking this, everything will run normally again.

This confirmation box breaks my code and I cant find a way to deal with it.

Is there any selenium webdriver api for this?

Cheers.

Comment: It is not clear in your post "what language you are using". Are you using Ruby or Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in ruby.
try using this  -  `@driver.switch_to.alert.accept`

this should hopefully click on Resend

Comment: totally worked!!

**for anyone interest this is the java code**

`driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

Comment: in python: driver.switch_to.alert.accept()